# Is Zodom a Virus?

Tags: ar-tonelico

In *Ar Tonelico 2* when Zodom appears in Lekra after EXEC_HIBERNATION was stopped Mir comments how it's cuter than other ones and that she wouldn't have made one so immature.

There are 2 things i can think of that Mir has created in the past, Song Magic and Viruses. so does that mean Zodom is a Virus and the song she sings is her version of EXEC_PAJA? if not then what did Mir create in the past which is like Zodom (only more mature)?

Comment: I could'nt find confirmation, so I'll just comment. Mir's Viruses and Zodom are indeed similar, and may be what Mir wanted to mean. And by that logic, the most mature virus Mir seems to have created is/was Ayatane, that was even able to act on his own free will.

Comment: ahhh . .i remember playing this game on PS2 . . 

are they have the same story line ?

Shurelia is my favorite Revytail :D

Answer (score 2):

They are similar (lifeforms created by taking data or feelings from the Binary Field and giving them form through Flip-Flop Conversion), but Mir is comparing it to the Shadow Mir virus she made and summoned for the final battle in AT1.

And the song Mir used there is EXEC_HARMONIOUS_FUSION/., a variant of her Harmonious song that underwent a Hymmnos Fusion that she made especially for quelling down the negative feelings Zodom was formed from. Plus, it should have been very obvious from the fact its beginning sounds very similar to the Harmonious Misha sang during AT1's final battle.